# MySql ignores memory settings

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, memory-usage, mysql5.6

I'm using MySql community server 5.6 on Ubuntu 15.04, I have /etc/mysql/my.cnf (no other config files). I've made changes to it and restarted MySql. When I use such query

```
SELECT @@key_buffer_size
```

(or some other config from my.cnf file) it returns the same value as in my.cnf.
I'm trying to minimize memory consumption, but after all efforts to do that MySql still starts ~20 threads and consumes ~370MB.

Could you please help me to find why MySql doesn't use (but sees) configs?

my.cnf (complete file content) is:

```
[mysql]
    port                           = 3306
    socket                         = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
    user                           = mysql
    default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
    socket                         = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    pid_file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

    myisam_recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

    max_allowed_packet             = 16M
    max_connect_errors             = 10

    datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

    log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_bin
    expire_logs_days               = 5

    sync_binlog                    = 1
    binlog_cache_size              = 4K
    binlog_stmt_cache_size         = 4K
    log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_error.log
    log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
    slow_query_log                 = 1
    slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql_slow.log

    tmp_table_size                 = 1K
    max_heap_table_size            = 16K
    query_cache_type               = 0
    query_cache_size               = 4M
    query_cache_limit              = 256K
    thread_stack                   = 128K
    open_files_limit               = 65535
    table_definition_cache         = 1K
    table_open_cache               = 2K
    max_connections                = 30
    key_buffer_size                = 8M
    thread_cache_size              = 0
    host_cache_size                = 0
    sort_buffer_size               = 32K
    read_buffer_size               = 8200
    read_rnd_buffer_size           = 8200
    bulk_insert_buffer_size        = 0
    join_buffer_size               = 128

    net_buffer_length              = 1K
    innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
    innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
    innodb_log_file_size           = 8M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_file_per_table          = 1
    innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 5M
    innodb_log_buffer_size         = 256K
    innodb_sort_buffer_size        = 64K
    innodb_ft_cache_size           = 1600K
    innodb_ft_total_cache_size     = 32M
```

Comment: I've tried also to change 
thread_cache_size              = 1
and
max_connections                = 5
And still there 21 Mysql's processes and 74% of RAM used by it(out of 512MB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to resolve it. In [bug of 5.6.10 version](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68287)

I've found a solution: to comment line

```
table_definition_cache         = 1K
```

Although I have version 5.6.27 it works greatly. Now MySql consumes less than 70MB.